# Class is managed, but is not listed in the persistence.xml file

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa-2.0

Estou com um problema que não estava antes de migrar para o JPA 2.0 . Recebendo mensagem de que todas as minhas classees / entidades não estão listadas no persistence.xml e mesmo depois de adicioná las continuo recebendo a mensagem.

https://snag.gy/T1dRi9.jpg

Segue o meu persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">


<persistence-unit name="PrevisaoVendasPU">
    <!-- <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/GerenciadorAcessoDB</non-jta-data-source> -->
    <provider>javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>br.com.previsao.model.Empresa</class>
    <class>br.com.previsao.model.Endereco</class>
    <class>br.com.previsao.model.Familia</class>
    <class>br.com.previsao.model.Historico</class>
    <class>br.com.previsao.model.Linha</class>
    <class>br.com.previsao.model.Produto</class>
    <class>br.com.previsao.model.Telefone</class>
    <class>br.com.previsao.model.Usuario</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/previsaovendas?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />

        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"
            value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="300" />



        <!-- <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" 
            /> <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" /> <property 
            name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" 
            /> -->
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Ao clicar no JPA faces o eclipse criou outro arquivo persistence .xml em branco foi só então colar o correto por cima :0

Comment: Se já resolveu o problema. Coloca a resposta e aceita a reposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao clicar no JPA faces pare acertar o problema, o eclipse criou outro arquivo persistence.xml em branco foi só então colar o correto por cima

Answer (score 0):

Clica com o botão direito no persistence.xml, em seguida clica em "Synchronize Class List".

Funcionou pra mim (JAVA/JPA)